# How big can be gradient of magnetic induction (in lab)

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

I'm thinking about magnetic levitation and how big force can push a diamagnetic when we put it in inhomogenious magnetic field.

As far as I know, force exerted on a diamagnetic is proportionald to $\chi/2*dB^2/dx$.
Where $\chi$ is diamagnetic susceptibility, $B$ is induction and $x$ is distance from magnet.

I'm just interested how much can $dB^2/dx$ term yeld in lab.

Comment: How much money do you have and are you allowed to use explosives? :-) OK, let's do it on the cheap and without explosions! A good way of estimating what you have to work with is the magnetic field of permanent magnets, which is around 1-1.5T. The size of these magnets is on the order of 1mm-1cm, so the magnetic field can me made to go from 1T to near zero over the course of 1mm, or so. Put that into your equation and see how much force you can get out of it! Your multiplier should be on the order of 100-1000 T^2/m, or so.

Comment: @CuriousOne And what if I have few thousand dollars?
BTW thanks for your comment.

Comment: Even that may not buy you much more than some better rare-earth magnets. The cost of a small superconducting magnet that could potentially exceed what can be done with cheap permanent magnets is probably in the tens of thousands of dollars, if not more, and you would need liquid He. You could probably generate much larger field gradients with a capacitor bank discharging into a gradient coil, but the repelling force there would be mostly from induction, not from diamagnetism. This may help with cost estimates for large magnets: http://mice.iit.edu/micenotes/public/pdf/MICE0188/MICE0188.pdf